# Can you use a render layer output as an image texture input in a shader for a separate render layer?

Tags: rendering, shaders, render-layers

I want to recreate the grass effect [t3ssel8r](https://www.youtube.com/c/t3ssel8r) has in his unity project as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thUXblUXKeU).

It looks like the best way to do this would be to have billboarded sprites for the grass. And to render the shadows on the ground w/o the grass first. Then sample the result from the ground render to determine the color of each sprite as it's rendered. This way, I can have each sprite be one solid color, while having that color be determined by the shadows. And I can rotate the sprites to face the camera without the color changing. This means I would need the output from rendering the ground to be available in the grass shader.

I've done some research and found [Malt](https://malt3d.com/), which lets you make a custom render pipeline, but I'd rather not dive into learning python and trying to decipher all that if I don't have to. Which brings me to my question: Is there a way to use the output of a render layer as a texture input in a shader in another render layer?